# Ember model with session data

Tags: session, ember.js, model, ember-simple-auth, ember-model

I have a problem with ember when I want to use a session data (companyId that is assigned to a user) in a model. I am using ember-cli and ember 0.13.1 with ember-simple-auth. Lets say I have a route called user/profile when I want to show information about company that the user is assigned to. In order to do that I need to retrieve a companyId that is assigned to a user from session and make a call with a model to my API. Currently the route for user/profile looks like that:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                industries: this.store.findAll('industry'),
                industryroles: this.store.findAll('industryrole'),
                company: this.store.find('company',this.session.get('user.companyId'))
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('industries', model.industries);
            controller.set('industryroles', model.industryroles);
      controller.set('company', model.company);
  }
});
```

Everything works when you go to that route from different route, but when you are in user/profile route and you press F5 then the this.session.get('user.companyId') is undefined.

Does somebody have an idea how I can solve that problem ?

Best regards
Pawel

Comment: If user can get access only to their company, you may solve this on backend: determine what user is requesting info and return their company.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not want to do it in my backend because I am using the same request also in other routes. I am wondering if I should inject the session to a model, but I have found in simple-auth forum that this is not suggested way of doing it. Another thing is that I register a user with a promise, which means that the models from user/profile route will execute after that promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you need to look in session.content setting (if you not overriding beforeModel hook in user/profile route, of course).

If there is two step data fetching in your case, you need to wait for session data in user/profile model hook, and only then you can get user.companyId.

Comment: I have posted my solution but it does not work properly. I could not find a solution to wait for the session to be set in beforeModel. Could you provide me some example how can i do that ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some solution. I have set an observer for session.user.companyId in route of user/profile. So currently my route looks like that:

```
//app/routes/user/profile.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    onSessionIsAuthenticated: function () {
    var isAuthenticated = this.get('session.isAuthenticated');
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return false;
    }
        var _this = this;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      company: _this.store.find('company',this.get('session.user.companyId')).then(function (data) {
        _this.controllerFor('user.profile').set('company', data);
      })
    });
  }.observes('session.user.companyId'),
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                industries: this.store.findAll('industry'),
                industryroles: this.store.findAll('industryrole')
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('industries', model.industries);
            controller.set('industryroles', model.industryroles);
  }
});
```

The rest industry and industry roles are still left in a controller. Now everything seems correctly but I am not sure if this is the correct solution for this problem. I am not sure if this is what you was in your mind @Microfed?

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still struggling with the problem described above. This is the solution:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                industries: this.store.findAll('industry'),
                industryroles: this.store.findAll('industryrole'),
                company: this.store.find('company', this.get('session.data.user.companyId'))
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('industries', model.industries);
            controller.set('industryroles', model.industryroles);
      controller.set('company', model.company);
  }
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: try `controller.setProperties(model)` instead of setting it individually.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. The problem is that session data hasn't been resolved when the model hook is called. You seem to have just changed how the session data was referenced.